# More eclipse insanity. Wrong JDK is set on imported projects

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Maybe its just me but almost everytime I import an Android project it does not compile.  First I need to set the Android SDK.  Thats reasonable. But then, I almost always need to reset the JDK. Usually from JDK 1.4 to JDK 1.6.  Now I really don't think too many people are out there developing android with JDK 1.4.  Perhaps they are, but its no where on my machine, and yet its often pre-selected on every Android project I import.  Its an annoying extra step, and I cannot imagine xCode doing something like this. Does anyone know why Eclipse does this?

Now some of these projects are not the most recent.  But what makes me think this is an eclipse issue is that often the error is that it won't compile because its not version 1.6  Which means that it must have been developed with the JDK 1.6.  Its usually an error involving @Override that I see saying it can't be used without JDK 1.5 or 1.6+.  I then check the JDK setting for the project and sure enough its at JDK 1.4.  Never 1.5, Never 1.3.

Comment: When was the last time you updated your Eclipse and ADK ?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2012.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://eclipse.org/

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation http://apache.org/

Comment: What is your default compiler compliance level for your workspace (Preferences > Java > Compiler > Compiler compliance level)?

Comment: @swayam My machine is a few months old, my install was less than a few months ago, updates have nothing to do with JDK 1.4 being selected unless there was something really wrong with the initial download.

Comment: @CodeDroid : Ah okay. I am trying to think of further possibilities.

Comment: @Swayam thanks.  An update could fix this but frankly I've seen it before on my local pc as well as my mac.

Comment: This question should be voted up! Be honest, you have seen this yourselves before!

Comment: Right click -> Android -> Fix project properties. Usually works every time. I dont see it being so hard. Im curious though why everything on this page seems to be downvoted

Comment: Well if eclipse did not fix the properties to begin with this would not be necessary! it might not be hard, but again are xCode developers sharing code in this way?  Fix projects everytime they are shared?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but as it's getting '1.4 from somewhere, perhaps typing javac -version and java -version might give you a starting point if it's something in the path??? (At a command line prompt - I mean)

Comment: it does. it gives me 1.6.  But this did not just occur today.  i have experienced this across machines.  On both PCs and MACs. I have come to expect that projects will not compile when the are imported.

Answer (score 2):

Set the project's JRE to an Execution Environment.  It's an extra layer of indirection that keeps you from referencing a JRE by its name in your particular workspace, helping make the project more easily shared.

Comment: So you are saying that whoever shares a project should set the JDK in this manner.  That might help, but few would know to do this.